# ASP.NET: How to re-flow GridView cells over multiple lines 

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have an application which contains a table with two columns: `messageid` and `messageDesc` . Inside the `messageDesc` column there is a message description. When I try to bind the GridView to the `messageDesc` column, it renders the entire column on a single line, requiring the user to scroll horizontally to view the complete text. I want to prevent this by having the description flow over multiple lines. How do I do this?

I have tried using the ItemStyle attribute but it's not working. Please suggest a solution. In addition to this, I can't change the database message content.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there any space in "description" ?

Comment: it dependeds,not necessary its plane texture with and with out space

Comment: add below style to your gridview, `word-break:break-all;word-wrap:break-word;overflow:hidden;table-layout:fixed;` and apply width of each column,

[link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1285203.aspx/1?how+to+fix+the+length+of+gridview+column)

Comment: That works for IE but not for firefox

Answer (score 1):

Warp label insdie div element and than try out this will surely work for you

```
 <asp:TemplateField> 
        <ItemTemplate>
             <div style="width:100px;">
                 <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="<%# Eval("description") %>"></asp:Label>
             </div>
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
```

or

```
<ItemStyle Wrap="true" Width="100px" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can display data in textbox using template field instead of bound field. See below, textbox code. Your TemplateField would look like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ReadOnly="True" Text='<%# Eval("MessageDesc") %>'
            TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The ReadOnly setting keeps users from editing the data while having it still enabled for them.  In Edit mode, of course you would set ReadOnly to false.

Comment: Actually, i implemented the solution earlier but the text box come up with scroll pan therefore am looking for the solution without textbox multiple line